# Selenium Java clear method will not clear the input field?

Tags: java, selenium

I ran into a little issue today while validating some input fields in our application.
Looks like we can't call the selenium java method `clear()` to clear the input and I know I can iterate over the string and use `sendKeys(Keys.Backspace)` but `clear` method should do the work?

Anyone else ran into the same issue and how did you work around this problem.?

Our app is built upon Ant libraries

Selenium

```
String hotmarketNameEdit = "ant-input";

    WebElement edit = driver.findElement(By.className(hotmarketNameEdit));
    edit.click();
    edit.clear();
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="label" class="ant-input ant-input-sm" value="AUTOMATION TEST - Thu Oct 21 09:54:15 MDT 2021" xpath="1">
```

Thanks for any inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally come across this issue quite a few times, that Selenium `.clear()` method does not work properly.

Selenium community is aware of this issue, please see the bug reported [here - ClearText does not work](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6741)

You can go through the above-mentioned link.

**Workaround :**

Majority of time, I try to simulate `Ctrl + A` to `select the text` and just press **delete** after that.

If You are using Java as a binding language, You can do the following

```
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input , I went down that route too :) and it partially worked , basically selected parts of the string visible and the rest left out. lol.
It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried JavaScriptExecutor?

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) indexWebDriver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value=''",edit);
```

check this one also

[How can I consistently remove the default text from an input element with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251916/how-can-i-consistently-remove-the-default-text-from-an-input-element-with-seleni)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this work around, passing both selecting and deleting keywords in one command

```
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a", Keys.DELETE));
```