# Java Selenium delete default input field value and add own values

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm currently having to venture into Selenium due to a project.
I'm supposed to load a page automatically, log in, click and then fill in a table.

Everything works until I fill out the table.
My Code:

```
public void inputGross(String gross){
inputGross.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE, gros);
```

The problem is that the input field already contains the amount `"0.00 €"`.
With the Clear command, the field empties, but since it first leaves the cell and then enters again, the default value `"0.00 €"` is created again.

What I have already tried:

```
inputGross.clear()
inputGross.sendKeys(gross)

inputGriss.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keyes.CONTROLL, "a"), Keys.DELETE, gross));

inputGriss.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROLL, "a"), Keys.DELETE, gross, Keys.RETURN));

inputGriss.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE, Keys.DELETE, Keys.DELETE, Keys.DELETE, gross, Keys.RETURN));
```

I have no more ideas.

I also tried using `Keys.ARROW_LEFT` to go to the left side and then delete everything. But that doesn't work either.

I really need help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Java clear method will not clear the input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69666100/selenium-java-clear-method-will-not-clear-the-input-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Actions.

This code should solve your problem:

```js
public void inputGross(String gross){
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  inputGross.click();
  for (char ch: gross.toCharArray()) {
            actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform();
        }
  actions.sendKeys(inputGross, gross).perform();
}
```